# Wildfly 10 can't find my jar resources

Tags: wildfly

i have a project that works very well in IntelliJ + WildFly 10. I have a WAR file that uses a JAR file, this jar file contains XHTML composite components.

When i put this WAR file inside deployments folder in WildFly 10 and try to start with standalone.bat i got the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: //D:/jee-ronaldo/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/content/easyrec-adm.war/WEB-INF/lib/myjar-web-1.0.jar/META-INF/resources/myjar/listPage.xhtml @49,93 action="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.goTo(cc.attrs.targetPage,'action','ADD')}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 50 more
```

I discovery that all beans inside my WAR file are not managed by CDI. I have a beans.xml file inside WEB-INF folder but i believe that CDI didn't work.

Comment: How are you building this WAR file?

Comment: Using mvn clean install command.